YOLO - training the model one epoch at a time
I am trying to make an app that trains a YOLO model, and after every epoch saves the statistics somewhere (to be sent to another part of the app), and then continue training the model in the next epoch.
I don't really understand how to make that. For example, I do:
model.train(data='...', epochs=1)
That will train it for 1 epoch, but how do I train the same for 1 more epoch? Does the argument epochs have to be equal to 2? Do I do resume=true? Do I load the model trained on the previous epoch from 'weights\best.pt' or 'weighs\last.pt'?

specify more details please, which framework are you using? isn't a for loop sufficient? for i in range(N): model.train(data=x, epoch=1).

I am using ultralytics YOLO. Also, only 'epochs' works. If I do it with epochs=1 over and over again after loading model=YOLO('..best.pt') will it be like a continued training proccess, or as it was trained for the first time?

The reason I am asking for this in the first place is that because I am trying to make some kind of client - server app on which the server will train a model, and I want the client to be updated of the progress and be able to stop the training process. I don't know how to send the statistics / updates if there are 100 epochs or stop the proccess and I don't even think there is a way, I haven't found anything or anyone talking about that.

in pytorch it will continue the training using the already trained weights, so u can send statistics

My question is that if this approach is just as training an epoch one after another without pause (like model.train(..., epochs=100).
model = YOLO("...name\\weights\\best.pt")
for epochs in range(...):
model.train(data='...data.yaml', epochs=1, name='name')
Because everytime a new 'name' folder is being created in 'Admins\runs\detect'. I just want this to work as you would normally train with an epochs argument equal to 100 or 200. I am just doing this so I can be able to easily stop the process and get the statistics.

for the second reply: define the statistics you want, collect them and send them. To stop the process you should make a function that waits for a signal that the statistics are good to stop.
